# int/BigInteger from hex returns wrong answer

Tags: java, int, hex, converters, biginteger

I have a Hex String (90) and I want to get it back to an integer value. What I've tried:

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(myhexstring, 16);
```

It returns 2316.

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(myhexstring, 16);
```

returns 2316 too.

What is the problem?

Comment: If you are getting `2316` it means you are passing in `90F` not `90`

Comment: Lets see how `myhexstring` is defined

Comment: @PeterLawrey: 90F is 2319, so it would be 90C

Comment: Could you upload an sscce? See www.sscce.org.

Comment: @musefan good point. I typed it into my calculator incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("90", 16));
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("90C", 16));
```

you get http://ideone.com/XBnFG7

```
144
2316
```

Comment: It's hard to confirm without more information from the OP, but surely it's too much of a coincidence for it to be anything else

Comment: @musefan I often use my mind reading powers, as unreliable as they are ;)